# Building communities based on multiple edges (Louvain Python)

Tags: python, graph, cluster-analysis, networkx

I have a df with multiple columns

| Warehouse | Warehouse Name | Store | Store Name | Owner | Owner Name | Seller |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| JFK1 | John F K 1 | Store 2 | Shore Line | LTR1 | Rakual | Big toys |
| ABL2 | Ab Linc 2 | Store 3 | MarkTech | LTR1 | Rakual | Amazon |
| JFK1 | John F K 1 | Store 5 | JBL | LTR1 | Rakual | Amazon |
| MNY5 | Mani Co | Store 5 | JBL | PRR1 | JHason | Decor |
| NXN9 | Nixon Pvt Ltd | Store 9 | Camera | LMR7 | Jose | EBAY |

In this DF, when any warehouse is linked to any store or any owner or any seller, they need to be part of the same community. the warehouse is the anchor to join to store, owner and seller.

So row 1, 2, 3, and 4 have at least 1 matching edge and should be a community

Code is pretty straight forward, Using Louvain,

```
# create a new graph for performing Louvain clustering
G = nx.Graph()

# Add edges trom DF
G.add_edges_from(df_sales[['WAREHOUSE', 'STORE']].values)
G.add_edges_from(df_sales[['WAREHOUSE', 'OWNER']].values)
G.add_edges_from(df_sales[['WAREHOUSE', 'SELLER']].values)

# Do louvain

partis = community.best_partition(G)
community_values = [partis.get(node) for node in df_sales['WAREHOUSE]]

# Set values to DF

df_sales['CommunityID'] = community_values
```

expecting something like

| Warehouse | Warehouse Name | Store | Store Name | Owner | Owner Name | Seller | CommunityID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| JFK1 | John F K 1 | Store 2 | Shore Line | LTR1 | Rakual | Big toys | 0 |
| ABL2 | Ab Linc 2 | Store 3 | MarkTech | LTR1 | Rakual | Amazon | 0 |
| JFK1 | John F K 1 | Store 5 | JBL | LTR1 | Rakual | Amazon | 0 |
| MNY5 | Mani Co | Store 5 | JBL | PRR1 | JHason | Decor | 0 |
| NXN9 | Nixon Pvt Ltd | Store 9 | Camera | LMR7 | Jose | EBAY | 1 |

but unfortunately, something is messing this up and every time I run the python code, I get different results and no. of communities

| Warehouse | Warehouse Name | Store | Store Name | Owner | Owner Name | Seller | CommunityID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| JFK1 | John F K 1 | Store 2 | Shore Line | LTR1 | Rakual | Big toys | 0 |
| ABL2 | Ab Linc 2 | Store 3 | MarkTech | LTR1 | Rakual | Amazon | 0 |
| JFK1 | John F K 1 | Store 5 | JBL | LTR1 | Rakual | Amazon | 0 |
| MNY5 | Mani Co | Store 5 | JBL | PRR1 | JHason | Decor | 2 |
| NXN9 | Nixon Pvt Ltd | Store 9 | Camera | LMR7 | Jose | EBAY | 3 |

Is there a reason why 4th row is not part of community 1. And is there a easier

I tried using enumerate instead of louvain as per code in [Group Data into Clusters Based on DataFrame Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71256560/group-data-into-clusters-based-on-dataframe-columns) but I realised, I don't want to group based on seller but all other columns when presenting in a map or out in excel

Comment: In your expected output, you show warehouses JFK1 and ABL2 both as part of community 0.  But you say " the warehouse is the anchor to join to store, owner and seller."  This indicates that two different warehouses cannot be in the same community.  There seems to be something wrong with your problem description, or your expected output.

Comment: This algorithm includes random components. If you want a consistent output you have to use a fixed `seed` (I'm assuming you are using [louvain_communities](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.community.louvain.louvain_communities.html)).

Comment: @ravenspoint - isn't the purpose of louvain to bring together nodes which are connected. So, if a store receives goods from more than 1 warehouse, we would expect to see that as a community won't we? The output generated, actually has 2 warehouses in the same community as well

Comment: Maybe so.  But it makes a nonsense of the statement "the warehouse is the anchor "  One or other must be wrong.

Comment: @Timus, thanks for this. Didn't know about randomize, I have started using it on other parts of my code!

Answer (score 0):

Using Louvain didn't really work for this scenario. Was able to complete the clustering using 1 while and 3 for loops in python

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).